# CSS no se está aplicando dentro de mi código PHP

Tags: php, html, css

estoy practicando desarrollo web, y actualmente pasé todo el sitio con el que estoy a  HTML a PHP para hacerlo dinámico, y estoy intentando hacer un calendario con los datos que estoy trayendo de una base de datos. El CSS se aplica a todo, excepto al HTML que está dentro del PHP, cosa que en el curso que estoy parece aplicarse normal, pero a mi algo me está fallando. Me fije si el archivo está siendo llamado , y está en estado 200 (Viendo el Google Chrome/F12/Red) y a todo lo demás, como dije, aplica los correspondientes estilos. A continuación adjunto el código, y la fracción de código CSS que estoy intentando aplicar.

```
<?php include_once 'php/header.php'; ?>

  <section class="seccion contenedor">
      <h2>Calendario</h2>

        <?php 
            try{
                require_once('php/db_connect.php');
                $sql =  ' SELECT evento_id, nombre_evento, fecha_evento, hora_evento, cat_evento, icono, nombre_invitado, apellido_invitado ' ;
                $sql .= ' FROM eventos ';
                $sql .= ' INNER JOIN categoria_evento ';
                $sql .= ' ON eventos.id_cat_evento = categoria_evento.id_categoria ';
                $sql .= ' INNER JOIN invitados ';
                $sql .= ' ON eventos.id_inv = invitados.invitado_id ';
                $sql .= ' ORDER BY evento_id ';
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
            }catch(\Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>

      <div class="calendario">
          <?php 
               $calendario = array();
               while($eventos = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

                   $fecha = $eventos['fecha_evento'];
                   $evento = array(
                        'titulo' => $eventos['nombre_evento'],
                        'fecha' => $eventos['fecha_evento'],
                        'hora' => $eventos['hora_evento'],
                        'categoria' => $eventos['cat_evento'],
                        'icono' => 'fas' . " " . $eventos['icono'],
                        'invitado' => $eventos['nombre_invitado'] . " " . $eventos['apellido_invitado']
                   );

                   $calendario[$fecha][] = $evento;
                } 
            ?>

            <?php 
                foreach($calendario as $dia=>$lista_eventos){ ?>

                    <h3><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        <?php 
                        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
                        echo strftime( "%a %e %B de %Y", strtotime($dia) ); ?>
                    </h3>
                    <?php foreach($lista_eventos as $evento){?>
                        <div class="dia"> //A este div le estoy intentando aplicar float y no lo hace
                            <p class="titulo">
                                <?php echo $evento['titulo']; ?>
                            </p>
                            <p class="hora">
                                <i class="fas fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <?php echo $evento['fecha'] ." " . $evento['hora']; ?>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <i class="<?php echo $evento['icono']; ?>"></i>
                                <?php echo $evento['categoria'];?>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                <?php echo $evento['invitado'];?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <?php } //end foreach $eventos?>

               <?php } //end foreach $dia?>



      </div>
      <?php $conn->close();?>
  </section>

<?php include_once 'php/footer.php'; ?>
```

Y acá el CSS

```
/* Calendario */
div.dia{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
div.dia:hover{
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

EDIT: Si le pongo 'display: flex;' usando el atributo style dentro del div, el estilo se aplica, pero si lo hago desde la hoja de estilos main.css no lo hace, no logro entender por qué. Además de lo mencionado, cuando busco el div class="dia" en Elementos (uso el Edge Chromium) me pone que está heredando los estilos del body que son un font-family y un background-color #f2f2f2.

Comment: No termino de entender lo que no funciona y como debería funcionar, si pudieras editar y explicarlo mas detalladamente sería genial

Comment: ¿has probado a inspeccionar tu `<div class="dia">` y revisar que efectivamente se está cargando? (en chrome, clic derecho en el elemento-> inspeccionar elemento) quizás el estilo está siendo sobreescrito por otro.

Comment: Intenta reduciendo el ancho del div, porque si es 50% y tienes márgenes (internos o externos) se agregan al ancho y no caben dos elementos. Te sugiero buscar otra opción como [flex](https://lenguajecss.com/p/css/propiedades/flexbox), creo que es más fácil.

Comment: @AlterLagos si, probé eso y si se está cargando, pero no aplica los estilos solamente

Comment: @Triby ahí pruebo, pero igual tampoco se están aplicando otros estilos que puse para probar, como un background-color negro o display: none